# Why is my jQuery animation not very smooth?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

After the delay, it completely just JUMPS across the screen to the new spot, and it only animates the height. For some weird reason this doesn't happen when using percentages, only the pixel position. However, I need to use the pixel position. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
<style>
    #Intro {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }

    #Picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 33%;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Picture').fadeIn(1000).delay(1500).animate({'top': '25px', 'left': '20px', 'height': '101px'},2000, 'swing');
    });
</script>


<body>

<div id="Intro">
    <img src="images/Triplid Logo.png" id="Picture" align="center"/>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: is #Picture an img element? Some HTML would be helpful so that peeps can play around with this with jsfiddle.net

Comment: If #Picture is an image, and that image REALLY BIG, then that could be a problem. Also, if #Intro is also a picture, or video, or even complex HTML, that could also be the problem. Or both. Need more info to help you out better.

Comment: Ok, yes Picture is an img element. Intro is just a holder. This is basically just a cool welcome page I'm attempting, so there isn't too much HTML, but I have added the body.

Comment: I attempted doing this with the image being small, and this same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt, I think you may have discovered a bug. I was able to reproduce the jumping and does indeed work when using percentages exclusively or pixel units exclusively - not a mixture of the two.

There is an open bug with jQuery here:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9505

As for ways to get around this. Since your image is absolutely positioned, you can measure the position (top/left) of the image on window.load and switch it's CSS from percentage to pixels using jQuery. Then perform the animation.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EHAR5/

Comment: After countless days of testing theories and asking on every site I could, YOU have just fixed it! I should bake you a cake, but I won't. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. Animate.css library effect didn't have that problem (i guess because it uses translate3d).

Version adopted to my needs:

```
HTML
<h1 class="move">Some text</h1>

CSS
@keyframes slide {
    from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    }
    to {
    opacity:1;
    transform: none;
    }
}

.slide {
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.move').addClass('slide'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `delay(1500)`. Between the fade and animation it's already taking 3 seconds, and with the delay it's 4.5 seconds.

I would also consider setting the `position` to `relative`:

```
$('#Picture').css({ "position": "relative" });
```

Here's a similar `shake` function you can look at for reference:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function() { 
    this.each(function(i) { 
        $(this).css({ "position": "relative" }); 
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) { 
            $(this).animate({ left: -25 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50).animate({ left: 25 }, 10).animate({ left: 0 }, 50); 
        } 
    }); 
    return this; 
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/JppPG/3/